# XmlSerializer not copying nested class values

Tags: vb.net, xmlserializer, deep-copy

I am using an XmlSerializer to DeepCopy an object, but somehow it's not copying the nested properties.

```
<TestClass()>
Public Class ObjectClonerTest
    ReadOnly _target As IObjectCloner = New ObjectCloner()

    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub DeepCopy_ComplexSourceObject_NestedObjectCopied()
        Dim source As New SerialisableComplexGenericParameterHelper()
        source.Data() = 1
        source.ComplexValue.Data() = 2

        Dim actual = _target.DeepCopy(source)

        Assert.AreEqual(1, actual.Data())
        Assert.AreEqual(2, actual.ComplexValue.Data())
    End Sub

    Public Class SerialisableComplexGenericParameterHelper
        Public Property Data() As Integer
        Public ReadOnly ComplexValue As New SerialisableGenericParameterHelper()
    End Class

    Public Class SerialisableGenericParameterHelper
        Public Property Data() As Integer
    End Class

End Class
```

The copy function:

```
Public Function DeepCopy(Of T)(ByVal pSource As T) As T Implements IObjectCloner.DeepCopy
    Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
        Dim binaryFormatter As New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))

        binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, pSource)

        memoryStream.Position() = 0

        Return DirectCast(binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream), T)
    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

XmlSerializer does not serialize ReadOnly fields. Removing ReadOnly fixed the issue.

Comment: Of course! Would still promote the field to a property though.

Comment: What do you mean by "promoting the field"?

Comment: I just meant to turn it into a property (I tend to consider that fields are inferior to properties). In general I avoid coding public fields as they can cause problems later - eg with anything that reflects for properties over your class.

Comment: Oh!! Now it's clear! I thought you were saying that the XmlSerializer would automatically turn the field into a property! (That would have been strange). The field is public here as it's just a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

`ComplexValue` is declared as:

```
Public ReadOnly ComplexValue As New SerialisableGenericParameterHelper()
```

This isn't a property - its only a field. Fixing this should sort it I think.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. I will accept the answer when SO allows it.

Comment: Oops, sorry, the answer is not correct, but it helped me understand the error.

Comment: What was the error then? - best to include it here to help other people.